# When doing history search, the time of the results is gone

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to find a JSFiddle I did about 7 to 8 hours ago.  So if I open up History on Google Chrome, I can scroll and scroll, and see some JSFiddle I did 20 minutes ago, and I have to scroll and scroll, for the hundred of URL I did in the past few hours. I can see the time, but it is very tiring to use the eyes to scan the favicons.

So I thought, why don't I just search by "jsfiddle"?  But when I did, the time is gone. They all show Feb 15 and I don't know which is which.

I basically just want to be able to see

```
11:22am JSFiddle
11:21am JSFiddle
11:07am JSFiddle
11:06am JSFiddle
11:02am JSFiddle
11:02am JSFiddle
3:36am JSFiddle
3:33am JSFiddle
```

and I will know it is the ones around the 3am ones.  Is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome has very bad history logging. My brothers history has said that he hasn't been to youtube for a week (When in reality he has been there every day)

There is no solution. I recommend reporting it as a google chrome bug (I have done so multiple times)

Press the three dots in the top, right corner. Click "help". Click "Report an issue".